# Faster Split-Apply-Combine

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm working on a large function that forecasts something over N years and then reshapes the data from wide to long and finally applies a couple more operations before returning the data frame. Most of the function runs incredibly fast, the last 4 or so lines take up over 50 percent of the time the function spends running. Since the data frame is quite large I need to reduce the time spent running those lines which are essentially a split-apply combine.

Here is an example of the input:

```
     df

     Year Number ACost BCost Condition  Data_set Backlog
      1   2002    8       0      10           A      1
      1   2002    6       0      4            A      6
      1   X       0       5      2            B      2
      2   2004    10      0      10           A      0
```

Here is the code slowing everything down, essentially preforming a weighted average and summing by groups:

```
     final = df.set_index(['Year',Number, Data_set])
     final = final.sort_index(axis =1)
     final['ACost_cond'] = final['ACost'] * final['Condition']

     final = final.sum(level='Year',Number, Data_set)
     final['Resulting_cond'] = final['ACost_cond'].div(final['ACost'])
      L = final.reset_index()
      L['Final_cond'] = np.where((L['Data_set'] == 'B'),L['Resulting_cond'],L['Condition']) 
      L.drop(['ACost', 'BCost', 'ACost_cond', 'Resulting_cond'], axis =1 , inplace = True)
```

Expected output:

```
     L

     Year Number         Final_Condition   Data_set Backlog
      1   2002                7.43             A      7
      1   X                   2                B      2
      2   2004                10               A      0
```

What is the best way to speed up the SAC for these?

Comment: the arguments in 'final.sum' should be in a list right? Why not use group by and transform? With this you will only sort the index at most once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a reference to the columns you want to group on.

```
c = [df.Year, df.Number, df.Data_set]
```

Next, find the `sum` of `Backlog`, `Condition`, and `ACost` inside a `groupby`.

```
i = df[['Backlog', 'Condition', 'ACost']].groupby(c).sum()
```

Next, calculate the values for `Final_condition`, these also require groupby operations.

```
j = (df.ACost * df.Condition).groupby(c).sum() / i.ACost 
i['Final_condition'] = j.fillna(i.Condition)
```

Finally, `drop` the unneeded columns and reset the index.

```
i.drop(['Condition', 'ACost'], 1).reset_index()

   Year Number Data_set  Backlog  Final_condition
0     1   2002        A        7         7.428571
1     1      X        B        2         2.000000
2     2   2004        A        0        10.000000
```

---

Edit; trying to squeeze out a bit more performance.

```
df['Final_Condition'] = df.ACost * df.Condition 

g = df[
        [
        'Backlog', 
        'Condition', 
        'ACost', 
        'Final_Condition', 
        'Year', 
        'Number', 
        'Data_set'
       ]
].groupby(['Year', 'Number', 'Data_set']).sum()

g['Final_Condition'] = \
    np.where(g.index.get_level_values('Data_set') == 'B', 
        g.Condition.values, (g['Final_Condition'] / g['ACost']).values
)

del g['Condition']
del g['ACost']

g.reset_index()

   Year Number Data_set  Backlog  Final_Condition
0     1   2002        A        7         7.428571
1     1      X        B        2         2.000000
2     2   2004        A        0        10.000000
```

Comment: Awesome, now I won't define the columns I want to group by, by their names. Index reference in `c` suffices to define `j`. Didn't know that, and this is really cool.

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 yes, really useful when you're trying to group a dataframe with something that isn't actually a part of the dataframe!

Comment: It will save so much code from now on because I don't have to artificially enrich the DataFrame beforehand.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The code works but I didn't see a huge improvement in overall speed only about 0.6 seconds. It looks like the time to run was mostly just redistributed. Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @EEPBAH May I know the current run time of your data as well as its size?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The input df is 4105704 rows × 20 columns, this bit in original code ran in about 10.28s and your modified version runs in about 9.44s.

Comment: @EEPBAH Added a new solution. Essentially the same concepts, but I'm squeezing out as much performance as I can get.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ can you explain the purpose of the backslash after g['Final_Condition'] =     ,also why are you double bracketing the set of columns your going to be grouping instead of just grouping the whole df?

Comment: @EEPBAH it's faster to only group the subset of columns that you need to, instead of the whole thing. I was assuming your actual dataframe would have more columns you were not interested in. Also the backslash is the line continuation character. I use it to split one line of code across many lines for readability.